# How to compute the derived functor of bounded derived categories of hereditary algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, homological-algebra, quivers

Let $\Lambda$ be
a finite dimensional algebra given by the quiver
$$\cdot\leftarrow\cdot\leftarrow\cdot\rightarrow\cdot.$$
It can be view as an triangulated matrix algebra.
$$\Lambda={A\  \ M\choose0\ \  A}$$.
$(D^{b}(mod A),D^{b}(mod \Lambda),D^{b}(mod A))$ is a recollement of bounded derived categories.
Where six triangle functors are given by the derived functors of the following functors
\begin{aligned}
&i^{*}({X\choose Y}_{f})=Coker f,\ \ \ \ \ \ \  && i_{*}(X)={X\choose 0},\ \ \ \ \ \ \  &&i^{!}({X\choose Y}_{f})=X,\\
&j_{!}(Y)={M\otimes_{\Lambda''} Y\choose Y}_{1},\ \ \ \ \ \  \ & & j^{*}({X\choose Y}_{f})=Y,\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  &&j_{*}(Y)={0\choose Y}.
\end{aligned}
The above functors can be seen in https://file03.ixueshu.com/api/preview/pdf/image/pc/1000039868189510/p1.img

**Qustion**: How to compute the six functors in recollement of triangulated categories?
For example $j^{*}{X\choose Y}=?$, $j^{*}{X\choose Y}[1]=?$,$i^{*}{X\choose Y}=?$,
One can see $j^{*}{X\choose 0}=0$ as a stalk complex at 0.
$j^{*}{X\choose 0}[1]=0?$ (is it a 0 complex in $D^{b}(mod A)$?).
In fact, ${X\choose 0}[1]$ is a stalk complex at 1.

Thank you

Comment: I've fixed some tex, and added a few tags; feel free to revert if you don't like the changes. The link you include is the first page of a particular paper, as an image file and not a pdf. I find this very strange. Are you saying that the six functors you're interested in are found in the body of the paper of which you shared an image? It's also not clear to me what $A$ and $M$ are -- I imagine there are multiple ways that one could decompose $D^b(\Lambda)$ as a recollement of smaller categories.